# How to change the sample rate in jack audio?

Tags: audio, jack

I'm a relative beginner at audio, so please forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this question! I've been trying to change the sample rate from 44100 to 11025 Hz in jack audio (I'm using a Scarlet 4i4 3rd generation).

I'm trying to change it within a script in C (I know you can do it on command line or with qjackctl), so I was wondering if a) there was a simple way to do this with jack_client_open (the input parameters from what I understand don't seem to provide an option for sample rate but as a beginner I would not be surprised if I'm completely mistaken :)) or b) if there was a way to use something like system to call a command line prompt within C code but that would output the "client" that is created/opened so that I could utilize it further down in the function. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't change the samplerate from your Jack client. The samplerate is defined in the Jack server and your client uses this samplerate.

You can't change it on the fly. For example, if you change the samplerate from *QjackCtl* you will have to restart your Jack server to make it effective.

I guess you could use a system call from your application to start the Jack server with the desired samplerate, but again it will not "output the client". It will launch the Jack server which you can then connect your app.